# Forcing Exact Outputs for Integrate

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following triple integral:

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Integrate[
   E^(-v1 - v2 - v3) (v1 + v2 + v3)/3, {v3, 2 v1 - 5/2 v2, v2}], {v2, 
   4 v1/7, 5 v1/7}], {v1, 0, Infinity}]
```

I'm hoping to get the exact answer (as messy as it might be), but when I evaluate this (or even just the inner two of three integrals), Mathematica computes decimal approximations, rather than the fractions and powers of e that I need. For example, the inner two integrals evaluate to:

```
E^(-6.5 v1) (E^(4.35714 v1) (-0.777778 - 0.833333 v1) + 
   E^(4.07143 v1) (0.333333 + 0.404762 v1) + 
   E^(4.57143 v1) (0.444444 + 0.428571 v1))
```

but I'm fairly certain each of those coefficients is actually the decimal approximation of a rational number. Is there a way to force Mathematica to show me the exact expression instead?

Comment: I get an exact result - try restarting kernel and re-do...

Comment: Tried it. Still getting results like the above.

Comment: What version of MMA and what O/S are you on?

Comment: Running Mathematica version 9.0.1.0 on Mac OS X version 10.9.5.

Comment: *Hypothesis non fingo*... as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/XeVTqfy.png), exact results (on 9.0.1 Windows)

Comment: On my Mac with version `9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)`, I get `49/6885`. This is the same result that I get with version 10.1 on my Mac

Comment: You can write the integrals more compactly as `Integrate[
 E^(-v1 - v2 - v3) (v1 + v2 + v3)/3, {v1, 0, Infinity}, {v2, 4 v1/7, 
  5 v1/7}, {v3, 2 v1 - 5/2 v2, v2}]` which gives same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Trace[Integrate[
  Integrate[
   Integrate[
    E^(-v1 - v2 - v3) (v1 + v2 + v3)/3, {v3, 2 v1 - 5/2 v2, v2}], {v2,
     4 v1/7, 5 v1/7}], {v1, 0, Infinity}]]
```

Check one line before the result. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Give a positive vote then :)

Comment: Someday I'll have enough reputation to do that... :)

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: I'll check it out. I am new in this community!Thank's.

Comment: @NickMpountouropoulos Thanks for fixing it. (+1).  Also if you put an @ in front of my user name, I'll get notified of your response.  (Authors are automatically notified, so I used it with your name just for demonstration purposes.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank's.